# Salvar e atualizar entidades

Tags: c#, entity-framework

ou pessoal estou tentando dar uma melhorada no meu método genérico que adiciona e atualiza, segue o código:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(T entity)
{
     if (entity.Id == 0)
     {
         context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
     }
     else
     {
        var query = context.Set<T>().Find(entity.Id);
        context.Entry(query).CurrentValues.SetValues(Entity);
     }
     //context.Entry(entity).State = entity.Id == 0 ? 
     //                     EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

já dei uma boa pesquisada na internet e não encontrei algo mais performático ou mais Clean, se alguém poder me ajudar com alguma biblioteca agradeço desde já.

Comment: Está funcionando? tem algum problema, ou é mesmo como está escrito o código que te incomoda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tem isto aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
db.Set<Entidade>().AddOrUpdate(meuObjeto);
```

Aceita, aliás, vários objetos:

```
db.Set<Entidade>().AddOrUpdate(meuObjeto1, meuObjeto2, meuObjeto3);
```